# Processing saml signed response using idp meta data ? saml +adfs + idp

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs2.0

I am doing saml2.0 authentication as a service provider. after authenticating to my IP(identity provider) I am getting a response

like bellow

> > https://localhost:4200/map?SAMLResponse=pVRNj5swEP0riDvfkIDFIqXJJVK3u0pWe9hL5dhDQwUYecx2f35tKMmySmmrnvA8zbx5nnkmR9rUHTkAdqJFsPa7O%2fsrZEkcrCPmxFkcOXFaRk56iksnjJI0CU808GlgW88gsRLtnR26vm3tEXvYt6hoqzTkh4Hjp04QPgUJSRIS%2bO46SV9saweoqpaqofKsVIfE82rBaH0WqEgc%2br7X0M62tkaP4eplSwTFCklLG0CiGDlu7j8T3ZawMYn0LXbAqrICbltvTd0iGS62XN1JoQQTtV3kg3w5li4XUUSQRr5dGPlavenkNjXl6DZVy2vxrWIu7TqP8hI9nf1aMUBPyR5V7o2dinwc%2fFFR1eM82goO1jOte1hWgkM2OfZM06NteUXuzVk3k9ZxrzwrgzKJuZNR8J2Yw9rJIh3GdO2nCZyyVZT83SbXLx%2f3%2f2%2bT%2bzXv%2f5vgsT99B6YuB%2b2YspLN4C3rHtRZ8D%2b4pyEnoBKkfZNjRxW1vgj10D7ITalAzqexIr5%2f9fVB26%2brBsMuudrs6EarK1rkGueVAdE0%2fwSlkPC7Pax05yWF7%2fK0G3quBTLQj13Jio19J7CYVHN4%2fbAELTz3LnnX44zHu8o2pOrcGhNCoydiDeFNRwXED0icuqssGhXqRE2k4E3No22t3XOAslg0GCPM5Gn4UX9%2bCMkf9RPXUwX%2bJKn%2bRwipjP4bvHN4Ci93MMBk38szm%2f6axU8%3d&Signature=vY2pfmvhiy%2fhUmh1Gngn9WntOYU30sxjSU6JhSVLEWOVj6Y0bZM73eI6Ad%2fXRdOUwfqTx2vjtpVRqZJfe9I9%2fM0SkyQ90bGdHUpK%2bMdrrm6KuXoC1SR1MRZAV1ebRcKwlLOcK4KO39TC%2bQs0jVGtvBeO9w4ypPzWRp1OOFQybbd%2bE7Q7xj6DcRlhiyli5S5TfGnK%2f5D9nj3ZEiZWPjn9FFKVfAWpuqMyDPbeDibktl3jLmvih8B1mbOLx%2fRyQZe8Klx381BqZd7Bg8NzHoEvqRvdfrqEslnjZSuF5vCpSKFdKhZ7KQGazj66SnQbVUXB9UvT480tWlwjhwkraXY58Q%3d%3d&SigAlg=http%3a%2f%2fwww.w3.org%2f2001%2f04%2fxmldsig-more%23rsa-sha256 >>

Instead of xml response am getting like above and my question is how to process it ?

Comment: A SAML Response is deflated and base64 encoded. To get the SAML you just inflate and base64 decode the SAMLResponse parameter

Comment: Thanks @codebrane how to inflate it in python i dont know how to inflate it.i know how to decode it but dont know how to inflate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the response, plug the below into e.g. [this](https://developer.pingidentity.com/en/tools/saml-decoder.html).

```
pVRNj5swEP0riDvfkIDFIqXJJVK3u0pWe9hL5dhDQwUYecx2f35tKMmySmmrnvA8zbx5nnkmR9rUHTkAdqJFsPa7O%2fsrZEkcrCPmxFkcOXFaRk56iksnjJI0CU808GlgW88gsRLtnR26vm3tEXvYt6hoqzTkh4Hjp04QPgUJSRIS%2bO46SV9saweoqpaqofKsVIfE82rBaH0WqEgc%2br7X0M62tkaP4eplSwTFCklLG0CiGDlu7j8T3ZawMYn0LXbAqrICbltvTd0iGS62XN1JoQQTtV3kg3w5li4XUUSQRr5dGPlavenkNjXl6DZVy2vxrWIu7TqP8hI9nf1aMUBPyR5V7o2dinwc%2fFFR1eM82goO1jOte1hWgkM2OfZM06NteUXuzVk3k9ZxrzwrgzKJuZNR8J2Yw9rJIh3GdO2nCZyyVZT83SbXLx%2f3%2f2%2bT%2bzXv%2f5vgsT99B6YuB%2b2YspLN4C3rHtRZ8D%2b4pyEnoBKkfZNjRxW1vgj10D7ITalAzqexIr5%2f9fVB26%2brBsMuudrs6EarK1rkGueVAdE0%2fwSlkPC7Pax05yWF7%2fK0G3quBTLQj13Jio19J7CYVHN4%2fbAELTz3LnnX44zHu8o2pOrcGhNCoydiDeFNRwXED0icuqssGhXqRE2k4E3No22t3XOAslg0GCPM5Gn4UX9%2bCMkf9RPXUwX%2bJKn%2bRwipjP4bvHN4Ci93MMBk38szm%2f6axU8%3d
```

You'll see the response.

Programmatically, use a library e.g. [this](https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml).